# How does Git compute SHA hashes so quickly?

Tags: java, git, scala, hash, sha

I know git is fast but I have only recently found how fast it really can be.

In one of my projects, I am trying to compute SHA-256 hashes of a huge file (82 MB with 850k rows) and it took over a minute to compute it (includes hashing and a couple of other small operations).

Even with SHA-1, it took me 30+ seconds while git seems to be doing it in just a second or two.

I am computing the hash in Scala using java's `Security` API by combining all the lines of the file.

```
val lines = Source.fromFile(filePath, "UTF-8").getLines().toList
MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256")
.digest(lines.mkString("\n").getBytes).map("%02x".format(_)).mkString
```

So, how does Git do it so quickly, or rather the more important question, why is my method so slow?

Edit: For those not familiar with scala syntax, `lines` will have all the lines of the file in a `List` and `mkString` method returns a string of all the elements in the list combined with the given separator.

Comment: Have you examined the source for Git?  That would be the place to start.

Comment: @JimGarrison, I tried to look for it but I didn't find the exact code that was actually doing the hashing. Also I am not very familiar with C code and I don't think I would be able to understand it much.

Comment: Parsing, putting this to a data structure (list), combining, getting bytes again... a lot of extra work. Didn't you try to read bytes directly from your `InputStream` (in 4k chunks) and feed them to the `MessageDigest` instance for update? That could be much faster.

Comment: Reading raw bytes as @RomanPuchkovskiy suggests is probably closer to what Git is doing anyway. Git doesn't care about lines, it will hash text, binary, it's all the same to Git. It only cares about lines when calculating diffs.

Comment: @RomanPuchkovskiy. The reason I was putting it into a List was because I needed that for another operation in the middle. But still, could that parsing make it SO exponentially slow? I will try with the approach you suggested and will see the performance.

Comment: What's with the downvotes?

Comment: I would say the git being written in C vs Scala can also affect the performance a bit

Comment: @pedrorijo91. Yeah of-course. That's a given, almost every time. But I'm still surprised that its taking this long.

Comment: @pedrorijo91: actually, [the SHA256 implementation in Git](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/block-sha1/sha1.c) (originally based on Mozilla's, but completely changed over time) is at least partially written in hand-optimized assembly, although Git will prefer to use the platform's native implementation (e.g. OpenSSL, Apple CommonCrypto, etc.) if there is one. But I don't think that's the problem, since I expect the JRE's implementation to also be a native method with hand-optimized code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Reposting my earlier comment (extended).

What you do is:

1. Read bytes
2. Convert them to characters
3. Split the character stream to lines
4. Store those lines into a list
5. Again concatenate those lines into a string
6. Take its bytes again
7. Compute hash of those bytes

Steps 2-6 seem unnecessary. I would recommend to read bytes from your initial `FileInputStream` in chunks (for example, of 4k) and feed them to the `MessageDigest` for update. That would just perform steps 1 and 7.

```
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(fileName);
byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
while (true) {
    int read = is.read(buffer);
    if (read < 0) {
        break;
    }
    md.update(buffer, 0, read);
}
is.close(); // better be done in finally
```

As for sha1 performance, here is what I got for `time sha1sum <file>` where file is 179Mb:

```
real    0m0.607s
user    0m0.588s
sys 0m0.016s
```

Comment: It looks like the extra process was making it a lot slower. I've tried to just read the bytes and give them to hasher like the way you suggested and now its taking around 30 seconds which previously was about 65 secs. Though it's twice as faster, 30 seconds still seems like a lot of time especially when Git is able to get it done so fast. I'll keep looking for a better way and thanks for the answer.

Comment: That's strange, I've tried to compute sha1 hash with the above code on the same 179Mb file and it took `real 0m1.192s`. Twice slower than `sha1sum`, but not an order of magnitude. I've repeated both tests several times to let the system cache and so on. Some profiler may help you pinpoint the problem.

Comment: A funny fact: after emptying FS buffers+caches http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87908/how-do-you-empty-the-buffers-and-cache-on-a-linux-system java program is **faster**: it takes 1.4 sec, while sha1sum takes 1.7 sec.

Comment: Woah. Faster than the native performance, That's interesting!

Answer (score 1):

The hash computation is redirected at compile time to a specific implementation in [cache.h](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/cache.h).  The underlying platform may provide an optimized (e.g., assembler or machine-dependent C coded) hash routine.  Of course, your Java implementation may or may not also provide such a routine.

If the platform does not have its own implementation, Git [provides one written in C](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/block-sha1/sha1.c) that works on large memory blocks, and still has some hand-tweaks and inline `asm`s with architecture and compiler `ifdef`s.

Answer (score 1):

Git undoubtedly is faster, but 30 seconds for SHA-1 is not so great.

So I ran a test in java:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    byte[] bytes = createSha1(new File("src\\main\\resources\\200mb_file.zip"));
    System.out.println(new String(bytes));

    long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long duration = (endTime - startTime);
    System.out.format("Duration: %dms\n", duration);
}

private static byte[] createSha1(File file) throws Exception  {
    MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
    InputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    int n = 0;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
    while (n != -1) {
        n = fis.read(buffer);
        if (n > 0) {
            digest.update(buffer, 0, n);
        }
    }
    return digest.digest();
}
```

Output:

```
Duration: 1531
```

My guess what is causing your slowness is the fact you are inputting it to a list rather the directly using it as a stream.